# What level of formality is used in companies and web pages?

Tags: translation, keigo, formality

I'm new here, and I'm full of doubts... (sorry) 
Today I want to ask about how should I address people that work in a company in a webpage?

I was recently hired at a consultancy agency to translate their web page to Japanese. I already with the basic buttons from the webpage and everything. But when it comes to translating page's information that is addressing the reader, I don't know how should I write it (keigo, son keigo?) :(

What is the best choice?

I thank all for your help in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was recently hired at a consultancy agency to translate their web page to Japanese. I already with the basic buttons from the webpage and everything. But when it comes to translating page's information that is addressing the reader, I don't know how should I write it (keigo, son keigo?) :(

In-company web pages are usually just polite formal Japanese, so called "desu-masu" forms, without special respect language, unless you are dealing with some kind of personal issue like writing a medical form or something.

Answer (score 0):

I would have liked to just comment on Ben's answer, but my reputation doesn't allow me to.

I am doing the opposite, translating a Japanese website into English, and they use "desu-masu" forms. When they want to refer to their company, they sometimes use "弊社" or "私たち" as in:

> ユニフォーム胸部分に弊社のロゴを掲載させて頂いております。
>
> 私たちが生み出す価値のインパクトは行動の質と量の掛け算で決まります。

And when they want to address the reader, they use "あなた", as in:

> あなたは行動記録と睡眠状況をいつでも振り返ることができます。

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: +1 Very nice answer Alina.